# Decode bluetooth data from the Indoor Bike Data characteristic

Tags: javascript, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to use the Fitness Machine Service + the Indoor Bike Data characteristic to get the cadence data. By using the nRF Connect Android App I can see that the data is there, sample data:

```
inst. speed  8.5km/h
inst. cadence 45.0 per min
inst. power 8W
Heart rate 0 bpm

//same data as hex 44 02 52 03 5A 00 08 00 00
```

Looking at spec for the Indoor Bike Data characteristic it says that the flag field should be encoded as 16bit([spec](https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Sitecore-Media-Library/Gatt/Xml/Characteristics/org.bluetooth.characteristic.indoor_bike_data.xml)) but when I try something like,

```
const characteristic = await char.startNotifications()
characteristic.addEventListener('characteristicvaluechanged', (data) => {
  const flags = data.getUint16(0, true);
    
  console.table([ flags & 0x0,flags & 0x1, flags & 0x2,flags & 0x3, flags & 0x4,flags & 0x5, flags & 0x6,flags & 0x7, flags & 0x8,flags & 0x9, flags & 0x10,flags & 0x11, flags & 0x12,flags & 0x13, flags & 0x14,flags & 0x15, flags & 0x16])
});
```

which outputs:

[image]

The data doesn't match up with the above data from nRF Connect Android. Does anyone know why the data provided and the values in the screenshot don't match up and how I can get the rest of the data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your bitwise operation on the flags field does not look to be correct.

I have done the following:

```js
var ble_bytes = new Uint8Array([0x44, 0x02, 0x52, 0x03, 0x5A, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00]).buffer;
var view = new DataView(ble_bytes)

flags = view.getUint16(0, true);
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
  console.log('flags[' + i + '] = ' + (!!(flags >>> i & 1)));
}
console.log('Instantaneous Speed = ' + view.getUint16(2, true) / 100)
console.log('Instantaneous Cadence = ' + view.getUint16(4, true) * 0.5)
console.log('Instantaneous Power  = ' + view.getInt16(6, true))
console.log('Heart Rate  = ' + view.getUint8(8, true))
```

Which gave me the output of:

```
> "flags[0] = false"
> "flags[1] = false"
> "flags[2] = true"
> "flags[3] = false"
> "flags[4] = false"
> "flags[5] = false"
> "flags[6] = true"
> "flags[7] = false"
> "flags[8] = false"
> "flags[9] = true"
> "flags[10] = false"
> "flags[11] = false"
> "flags[12] = false"
> "flags[13] = false"
> "flags[14] = false"
> "flags[15] = false"
> "Instantaneous Speed = 8.5"
> "Instantaneous Cadence = 45"
> "Instantaneous Power  = 8"
> "Heart Rate  = 0"
```

Which indicates there is `Instantaneous Cadence present`, `Instantaneous Power present`, `Heart Rate present`. The field `Instantaneous Speed` is always present.

I've converted the bytes according to that and it seems to match with what you got from the nRF Connect app.

Comment: The fitness machine service spec shows that bit 2's polarity is reverse, that a true value indicates instantaneous cadence is not present.

Comment: @TomHarrington according to the [XML](https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Sitecore-Media-Library/Gatt/Xml/Characteristics/org.bluetooth.characteristic.indoor_bike_data.xml), with `bit 2` being `1` it requires `c3` which is the `Instantaneous Cadence`. I agree it seems to be inconsistent with the Fitness Machine Service Specification. You should probably raise it with the Bluetooth SIG as to which is correct.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't noticed that the PDF spec and the XML contradict each other.

Comment: The Bluetooth SIG have replaced the XML files with two documents. 1) `16-bit UUIDs` at https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/ and 2) `GATT Specification Supplement` at https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/. According to that last document the `flags` for `Indoor Bike Data` has `Instantaneous Power present` as bit `6` and `Expended Energy present` as bit `8`